# How to move a "sprite" more smoothly in C#

Tags: c#, keypress

I have gotten a Picturebox to move with (W,A,S,D) keys but it is very choppy and you can only press on key at a time. Is it any other way you can move a "sprite" more smoothly?

This is my code i have tried:

```
    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        int offset = 10;
        if (e.KeyChar == 'a')
        {
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X - offset, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == 'w')
        {
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, pictureBox1.Location.Y - offset);
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == 's')
        {
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, pictureBox1.Location.Y + offset);
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == 'd')
        {
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + offset, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I assume this is WinForms. Trying to change positions of UI controls causes the form to reflow and is extremely slow; you will never get good performance that way. If you absolutely must use WinForms, create a single `Canvas` control and do all your drawing inside that.

Comment: WinForms is not a game engine; it's for building business forms. If you're building a game, you probably want to use some sort of game engine like Unity or similar.

Comment: a) Moving by 10 pixels is choppy. b) winforms wil not synch the animation with the monitor, so it will always be uneven. c) do all drawing yourself, best onto a PictureBox or a Label. Don't draw onto a Panel! Drawing onto a DoubleBuffered Form is possible but won't easily allow for growth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off updating the location internally instead of assigning it a new value by calling `pictureBox1.Location.Translate(offset, offset);`

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point.offset?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Point_Offset_System_Int32_System_Int32_

Answer (score 0):

To extend off of Babak and answer your other part (only pressing one key at a time), change your else if to just a series of if statements.  With else if, it breaks out of the sequence as soon as one of them is true, meaning that once you press one key, it doesn't look for the others.

Comment: `KeyPressEventArgs.KeyChar` can only contain one keypress; he doesn't want to look for others.